# Best way to find Facebook/Twitter/Google Friends using the same app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook, asp.net-web-api

I am building MVC C# webapi backend for my mobile app, which uses one's Facebook/twitter/Google account to signup. Now, I want to get friends list corresponding to individual's account who are using same app.

Well this is where my problem starts, would I have to pull request every time or will I have to manage a table for this purpose or is there some other best practice.

Any help/guidance would be appriciated

Answer (score 1):

Once you create a App via the facebook app you can use FQL to get the names based on your applications id

Something like

SELECT uid, name FROM user WHERE is_app_user AND uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())";

You you basically use the facebook API to make a request to facebook which will return a JSONArray, you can parse out that a array to get a list of users.

Here is a very similar question
[Facebook API friends who use same app android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13853804/facebook-api-friends-who-use-same-app-android)

Answer (score 0):

I'm familiar with the Facebook API.  Take a look at http://developers.facebook.com.  First, you need to request permission from the user to access a list of his friends.  Once you have that, you can query the open graph to get a friends list.  Take a look at the documentation on permissions to learn how to request permissions and which permissions you need to request.

You could create a cache and store it locally.  However, this data will change.  If you do cache it in your own system, make sure to invalidate it regularly and refresh it.  I pull the data each time I need it, and cache it just for immediate use.