# How to get friends email in facebook in graph api

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have developed an App,where i need friends email who is using this app.And  how to get app invite response, which user getting the app invitation.

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13853804/facebook-api-friends-who-use-same-app-android

Comment: that thread is from 2012 and FQL is deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only get the email of a user who authorized your App with the `email` permission. You can NOT get the email of all friends.

Just use `/me?fields=id,email` to get the email of an authorized user and store it in your database.

Comment: he is not asking for all the user's email. He is asking for only those who are using the same app.

Comment: i know that. see the second paragraph. that´s how you can do it.

Answer (score 1):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,email
```

That's the easiest way to get the email of the user who authorized your application. Other than that, you can't get the email of the user who authorized your app. They should authorize the app as well for you to get their email.